# apache spark Streaming error

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working with maven under apche spark (streaming). And with scala programming.
In fact, I have a small problem with the following instruction:

```
val sc= new StreamingContext(conf , Seconds(1))
```

If I lace the instruction the code is correct.

This is my full code (Network Word Count) :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext} 
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel 

object WordCountStreaming { 
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    val conf = new SparkConf() .setMaster("local")
           .setAppName("WordCountStreaming") 
           .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true"); val sc= new 
    StreamingContext(conf , Seconds(1)) val lines = 
      sc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt, 
    StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) sc.start() sc.awaitTermination() 
  }
}
```

Comment: please add error log and code

Comment: import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}  
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
object WordCountStreaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .setAppName("WordCountStreaming")
    .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true"); 
    val sc= new StreamingContext(conf , Seconds(1))
     val lines = sc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    sc.start()             
    sc.awaitTermination()  
  }
}

Comment: You know you can add it in the question (I did it for you) ?

Comment: thanks karotch  . I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here can you please try to give "local[*]" or "local[2]" in master because spark streaming cant works with the single thread so please try it with more than one thread in master if you run it on local.

Comment: Error maven when compiling. I have attempted to correct it, if I leave the above instruction. The error will disappear val sc= new StreamingContext(conf , Seconds(1))

Comment: SEE USE THE CODE ! HOW CAN WE REPLY ?!